# script for autosaving Excel sheet

Tags: excel

Can you please give me a clue or coding ... which will save my opened Excel sheet (even if minimized) every 1 minute in a specified path...

without hampering any operation of Excel... because through web query function I will update the sheet from web ...

```
<html>
<head>
```

var intInterval = 0 importquotes();

```
function importquotes()
{
filename = "E:\\Desktopp\\ami\\Daily.csv";//// ( This is the file i want to save periodically)
AmiBroker = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application" );

 AmiBroker.Import( 0, filename, "lanka.format" );
 AmiBroker.RefreshAll();
 }
 </script>
 <button onclick="intInterval=window.setinterval('importdata()',60000);">
 start
 </button>
 <button onclick="intInterval=window.clearinterval(intInterval);">
 stop
 </button>
 </body>
   </html>
```

In the avobe code you can see i am importing Daily.csv data into my database.... i want to save that excel sheet at 1 minute interval ....

Comment: Nope. Try yourself and come back once you got stuck. You don't get the codez here.

Comment: I tried several times... failed everytime.... i dont want a script here.... a clue 2/3 lines coding may help.... 

how to save an active excel sheet at regular interval .... ?

Comment: Ah, ok. Well I can't help here, but hopefully one of the Excel gurus out there...

Comment: thanks hopefully gurus will come and rescue me ....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually "How to save anything to my local computer from a HTML program (i.e. JavaScript)". If you're running on IE, Chrome, any Web browser due to security concerns the answer is no way. But, try Microsoft HTA and search for ado = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream"); and fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); those are the two available interfaces to access local computer file system. Use ADO if your data contains none ANSI characters e.g. utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like the below for use in VBScript, but to save rather than read:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Scripts\New_users.xls")

intRow = 2

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    Wscript.Echo "CN: " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
    Wscript.Echo "sAMAccountName: " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value
    Wscript.Echo "GivenName: " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
    Wscript.Echo "LastName: " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Quit
```

You can put the 1-minute timer in either Excel in a VBA macro or code it in VBScript.